# What are the main advantages/benefits of upgrading from Rails 2.x to 3.x? Should we wait for the next release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are lots of sites documenting the new features in Rails 3.x, like here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html.

But we are curious to know what people consider the main advantages of Rails 3.x over 2.x, and more importantly, whether people considered their upgrade worth it (i.e., would they do it again, given the choice, or would they wait for the next release)?

In particular, performance seems to be a primary benefit highlighted with 3.x, but have people actually experienced a speed increase with the new release?

Thanks!

Comment: I've upgraded a couple of apps from 2.3 to 3 and would do it again. Speed improvement and better code. If you are already on 3 it shouldn't be a hard upgrade. You should upgrade now, and then upgrade to 3.1 when it is launched

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! When is 3.1 set to be launched?

Comment: completely unknown, it's in active development. Figure 1 year away

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! BTW, why did you post this as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: b/c I didn't go into details on the main advantages, just a quick opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should.

1. New Active Record syntax
2. Very sexy routing
3. And tasty bundler

Only those three 3 points for me makes my life better :) Of course there are more beautiful things in new Rails

Comment: you can easily use bundler with Rails 2.3 too

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 is leaps and bounds better than Rails 2. The new ActiveRecord implementation and improved routing are quite good at cleanly expressing code that would be considerably messier in Rails 2.

The bundler (combined with rvm) is the real kick in the pants, however. With it you can be much more cavalier about messing around with gems, which translates to less brittle, more up-to-date libraries.